# How to check if class has methods added by aspect?

Tags: java, aspectj, inject

Suppose I have a simple class:

```
public class TestClass {
   /*...*/
}
```

I created an aspect which injects new method to this class:

```
public aspect TestAspect {
    public void TestClass.aspectMethod() {
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

Now, how can I check if `TestClass` has method added by `TestAspect` in runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to simply reflect on the class:

```
TestClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("aspectMethod")
```

which will throw NoSuchMethodException if it isn't there.  Or if you have the bytes you could use a byte code visitor to check what methods exist in the byte code - but the reflective route would be less messing around.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that this will be the simplest way. I thought there are some non-reflective language features which can do this. Duck typing would be very useful feature for inter-type declarations in AspectJ.

Answer (score 1):

Andy's answer is the correct one, I just want to answer your follow-up question from the comment:

Duck typing is not a Java feature, but if you use ITD in order to make the class implement an interface and then have an instance of your aspect-extended class you can use `instanceof MyInterface` in order to determine what you need to know. Other ways (also using reflection) are also available:

**Interface with the method you want to add later via ITD:**

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

public interface MyInterface {
    void myMethod();
}
```

**Sample driver application:**

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application application = new Application();

        // Use an instance
        System.out.println(application instanceof MyInterface);
        System.out.println(MyInterface.class.isInstance(application));

        // Use the class
        for (Type type : Application.class.getGenericInterfaces())
            System.out.println(type);
        for (Class<?> clazz : Application.class.getInterfaces())
            System.out.println(clazz);
    }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.Application;
import de.scrum_master.app.MyInterface;

public aspect MyAspect {
    declare parents : Application implements MyInterface;

    public void Application.myMethod() {}
}
```

**Application output:**

```
true
true
interface de.scrum_master.app.MyInterface
interface de.scrum_master.app.MyInterface
```

Comment: Simple, but nice method, kriegaex. I find this a little more "natural" than Andy's answer.